# Dataframe to.xml

Tags: python, pandas, xml

I am currently running a script in Python using 'to_xml,' that will convert each row of my dataframe into a .xml file using this code:

```
(data.to_frame().T.to_xml(output_dir / output_file , attr_cols=["disabled", "error-if-not-time", "interval-type", "type" , "verbose"],  
             row_name = "assesslet" , pretty_print = True))
```

Result: `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> <data> <assesslet index="Test" disabled="True" error-if-not-time="False" interval-type="empty" type="Test" verbose="True"/> </data>`

It's working pretty well, and it takes the appropriate columns into the .xml. However, I am trying to add another attribute after assesslet using different data from my dataframe, but I'm not sure how to do so using to_xml in the same code. For example:

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> <data> <assesslet index="Test" disabled="True" error-if-not-time="False" interval-type="empty" type="Test" verbose="True"/> <new_element polarity = "False"/> </data>`

Is there a way to add child elements or attributes using to_xml?

Comment: The question is unclear: first, it seems you're both changing the attribute value of the `interval-type` attribute from `"regexp"` to `"empty"` and, at the same time, adding a new `<new_element polarity = "False"/> ` after `<assesslet>`. Is that correct? Also, is there only one `<assesslet>` elment? If not, what happens to these changes with multiple `<assesslet>`s?

Comment: @JackFleeting Hi, I apologize, it should say `"empty"` in both of the `interval_type` attributes, I fixed it. That's correct, I am trying to add `<new_element polarity = "False"/>` after `<assesslet>` and there is only one `<assesslet>` element, so the end tag will be `</assesslet>`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing this - below is the one I personally prefer - basically, use an xml parser to parse the xml output of pandas and add the required element:

```
from lxml import etree
# let's say this is the output of `to_xml()`
asset = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
  <data> 
    <assesslet index="Test" disabled="True" error-if-not-time="False" 
               interval-type="empty" type="Test" verbose="True"/> 
  </data> """

#parse the xml
doc = etree.XML(asset.encode())

#create an xml snippet to insert 
new_elem = etree.fromstring("""<new_element polarity = "False"/>""")

#insert it into the parsed xml document
doc.insert(1,new_elem)
new_elem.tail="\n"
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

Output:

```
<data> 
    <assesslet index="Test" disabled="True" error-if-not-time="False" interval-type="empty" type="Test" verbose="True"/> 
  <new_element polarity="False"/>
</data
```

Comment: Hi Jack, thank you for your comment. The only question I have, is , is there a way to reasonably do this with 'to_xml?' The reason is because in some code before the `to_xml`, I am reading an excel file, and each row may have different cell information when I generate my .xml file. So, some .xml may have 'True', others 'False', etc

Comment: @george12 Not sure what you mean - what exactly may have 'True' or 'False'?

Comment: the excel file. So, in my first line of code, I have a `pd.read_excel('Path')` which reads my excel file. Then, I use `for name, data in df.iterrows(): data.to_frame().T.to_xml` to iterate through each row and make a new .xml. So, each row in my excel may have different data for each column, for example Verbose might be True or False, sometimes, for each row, and the .xml would be different.

Comment: @george12 I'm sorry, but it's still not clear. This answer works for the sample xml in your question, not the actual  Excel files you are dealing with. You may want to post a different question which shows different (short) output xml files and highlights the differences and different expected outputs.

Comment: Hi Jack, I'm getting an error saying `Error parsing line 2 column 25`, do you have any idea why it's doing that?